# Solutions of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions of
$$(at+bx+c)x'+(pt+qx+r)=0$$
Where $x$ is a function of $t$. Do it by a change of variables.
I managed to reduce the problem to a equation of the type
$xx'+mx+nt=0$ but I don't know if I can solve it.

Comment: You then can do $$x(x'+m) + nt = 0 \Rightarrow x'+ m= \frac{nt}{x} \Rightarrow x' = \frac{nt}{x} - m$$ This can be solved using the integrating factor.

Comment: Of course you have to find the domain of the solution first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $aq-bp\neq0$, namely
$$ at+bx+c=0,pt+qx+r=0$$
have the solution $t=t_0,x=x_0$. Let $s=t-t_0,y=x-x_0$ and the DE becomes
$$ y'=-\frac{ps+qy}{as+by} $$
which is homogeneous and can be solved easily. If 
$$ \frac{a}{p}=\frac{b}{q}\neq \frac{c}{r}$$
or
$$ \frac{a}{p}=\frac{b}{q}= \frac{c}{r}$$
It is easy to handle. You can handle yourself.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Terg, you are welcome.